# Add border and some other style to ImageView in runtime

Tags: java, android, imageview

My current code:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        ImageView imageview= new ImageView(this);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        imageview.setLayoutParams(params);
        layout.addView(imageview);
```

How can I add border to this imageview? I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:angle="90"
                      android:startColor="@color/image_border_start"
                      android:centerColor="@color/image_border_center"
                      android:endColor="@color/image_border_end" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp"
          android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/default_back_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and `iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.style);`, but then it shows just this border, not an image. Is it possible?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include another method that can be used. Please take a look and let me know if it works..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `R.drawable.style` as the background. Then add some padding to your `ImageView`. See the code:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style);
imageView.setPadding(2,2,2,2); // <- try out different values
```

Note: If the image (`bmp`) is square, then the border will appear perfectly around the image. If the image is non-square, then square border (in **green**) will appear around the image, and remaining space will be filled with black as shown below:

[image]

If however, you do not want this effect, but rather you want to stretch the image to fill the border, (no black space), then update your code as follows:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_header_selector);
imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP); // <- set the scale
imageView.setCropToPadding(true); // <- requires API 16 or more
```

This will have an effect as shown below:

[image]

*Note: (1) I have used green border for demo purposes. (2) Border size can be increased by changing the `android:top,left,right,bottom` values in your `style.xml`*

**UPDATE:** Another method how border can be applied to an image is by extending `BitmapDrawable` and then drawing a custom border rectangle. Declare a `class` as follows:

```
public class BorderDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {

    private static final int BORDER_WIDTH = 10;
    private final int[] GRADIENT_COLORS = {Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.RED};
    Paint borderPaint;

    public BorderDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap) {
        super(res, bitmap);
        this.borderPaint = new Paint();
        borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(BORDER_WIDTH);
        borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        // set border gradient
        Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getBounds().bottom, GRADIENT_COLORS, null,  Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        borderPaint.setShader(shader);

        // or the border color
        // borderPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        // draw
        canvas.drawRect(getBounds(), borderPaint);
    }
}
```

The use it as follows:

```
BorderDrawable drawable = new BorderDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

The above class can be modified to match your needs:

1) `BORDER_WIDTH` value defines the thickness of the border in pixels.

2) `GRADIENT_COLORS` colors define the colors used for the gradient in the border. Change them based on your values such as `image_border_start` etc..

The output will be a perfect border, irrespective of the dimension of the image.

Answer (score 1):

you could get do something like draw on the image itself, something along the lines of

```
public Bitmap addBorder(Bitmap bitmap){
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANIT_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Paint.BLACK);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.addRect(0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),Direction.CW);

    canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
    return bitmap;
}
```

not exactly sure if that is 100% correct but basically turn the bitmap into a canvas where you can draw on it and just use the dimensions of the image to draw a rectagle around the image

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.style)`. It just replaces the actual bitmap.

Instead of that, use:

```
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style).
```